# copy paste formatted text from another document without table cell

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy, cell

I am copy/pasting a formatted text from another document. The text is in the table of that document. when I remove the last character it removes the formatting for the last paragraph. however if I add the last character it take the cell of that table as well. what should be the optimum possible solution to take the formatted text from the document without table cell?

```
Private Sub DeInsert_Click()


    If De_List.ListIndex = -1 Then
        
        LBL DeInfoLB, " Please! select an Heading from above list.", True
        
    Else
        
        Dim cDeHeadR As Range
        Dim cSelection As Range
        Dim CelRange As Range
        Dim r As Long
        
        
        Dim cDeTbl As Word.Table
        
        r = De_List.List(De_List.ListIndex, 4)
                
        Set dTBL = oDoc.Tables(1)
        
        Set CelRange = dTBL.Cell(r, 4).Range
        CelRange.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
        
        CelRange.Copy
        Set cSelection = Selection.Range
        
        'Selection.Paste
        cSelection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code w/o any issues on Word 365. You could try below.

```
        cSelection.PasteAndFormat wdSingleCellText
```

Microsoft reference document:

> [WdRecoveryType enumeration (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdrecoverytype?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate the problem.

Two workarounds. Both of then might need bit more work.

```
' Copy the entire cell then use ConvertToText

Set CelRange = dTBL.Cell(r, 4).Range
CelRange.Copy
Set cSelection = Selection.Range
With cSelection
  .Paste
  .Tables(1).ConvertToText Separator:= wdSeparateByParagraphs, NestedTables:=False
End With


' Or use FormattedText
Set cSelection = Selection.Range
With cSelection
  .FormattedText = dTBL.Cell(r,4).Range.FormattedText
  ' that inserts the formatted range, but with a char(13) character at the end. So delete it.
  ' improvement suggested by @TimothyRylatt
  .Characters.Last.Delete
End With
```

Comment: Rather than count characters why not simply use `.Characters.Last.Delete`?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Good idea, I'll incorporate that, thanks!